# How to handle error thrown when sending to an email that is not existed in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, email

I am creating a commission approval module where when admin reject a commission request, it will delete the commission and send the email back to submitter. However, when I tested the code, it shows the error like this. After testing more about this error, I realized that this will only happen if admin rejects a user that has an email but does not exist in the mail server. I understand the code I used in Mail function is from older version, but this system was in development for many years. My question is how do I properly handle the error thrown? Preferably, I would want the system to redirect back to homepage and show the error page like how it is done in the code below. Take note that the current code is not enough to handle the error yet.

Error:

> Expected response code 354 but got code "503", with message "503-All
> RCPT commands were rejected with this error: 503-No Such User Here"
> 503 Valid RCPT command must precede DATA

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0aTz.png)

Code:

```
try { // email sending actual part here
    Mail::send([], [], function($message)use($data) {
        $message->from($data['from'])
            ->to($data["email"])
            ->subject($data["subject"])
            ->setBody($data["messages"], 'text/html');
        });
} catch(JWTException $exception){
    $this->serverstatuscode = "0";
    $this->serverstatusdes = $exception->getMessage();
}
    
if(Mail::failures()) {
    $this->statusdesc  =   "Error sending mail";
    $this->statuscode  =   "0";
    return redirect()->route('voyager.dashboard')
    ->with([
        'message'    => "Commission is rejected but fail to send email",
        'alert-type' => 'warning',
    ]);
} else {
    return redirect()->back()
    ->with([
        'message'    => "Commission is rejected and comment is sent via email successfully",
        'alert-type' => 'success',
    ]);
}
```

Comment: This is an issue with verifying your Mail sender. A miss-match between the sender mail and the  mail_username configured in the `.env`

Answer (score 0):

The basis of the error could be caused by `Mail Sender Verification Error`. When the `mail from` value differs from the `mail_username` in the `.env` can lead to such an error message.

For instance, if you are using `sender@mail.com` in the mail from the facade and in the .env you have configured something like 'sender@corporate.com' then you are bound to receiver the error.

To fix this ensure that the email that is configured in the `mail_user` in the .env file should be the one to use as the mail address `mail from helper`

From the above example the then in the ->from() should be `->from('sender@corporate.com')`